# casting signed to double different result than casting to float then double

Tags: c, casting, twos-complement

So as part of an assignment I am working if a expression : (double) (float) x == (double) x
returns awlays  1  or not.(x is a signed integer)

it works for every value except for INT_MAX. I was wondering why is it so? if i print the values, they both show the same value,even for INT_MAX.

```
x = INT_MAX ;
 printf("Signed X: %d\n",x);
 float fx1 = (float)x;
 double dx1 = (double)x;
 double dfx = (double)(float)x;
 printf("(double) x: %g\n",dx1);
 printf("(float) x: %f \n",fx1);
 printf("(double)(float)x: %g\n",dfx);
 if((double) (float) x == (double) x){
     printf("RESULT:%d\n", ((double)(float) x == (double) x));
 }
```

EDIT: the entire program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){



//create random values

  int x = INT_MAX ;


  printf("Signed X: %d\n",x);
  float fx1 = (float)x;
  double dx1 = (double)x;
  double dfx = (double)(float)x;
  printf("(double) x: %g\n",dx1);
  printf("(float) x: %f \n",fx1);
  printf("(double)(float)x: %g\n",dfx);
  if((double) (float) x == (double) x){
      printf("RESULT:%d\n", ((double)(float) x == (double) x));       
  }

  return 0;
```

}//end of main function

Comment: you are most likely losing precision when casting to float and then to double

Comment: Why do you think that it “works" for *every* value except `INT_MAX`?  Have you tried all of them?  (You should!)

Comment: Update your question to show your program's output. It would also be nice to show your entire program, including the `#include <stdio.h>` and the definition of the `main` function. And your mixing of `%f` and `%g` makes the output a bit confusing.

Comment: I think i now understand it. float can only store numbers that have mantisa of 31bits, and INT_MAX have more than that, so it loses precision while casting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` and `float` have most likely the same number of bits in their representation, namely 32. `float` has a mantissa, an exponent and a sign bit, so the mantissa must have less than 31 bit, needed for the bigger `int` values like `INT_MAX`. So there loss of precision when storing in `float`.